# LaTeX "\indent" creating paragraph indentation / tabbing package requirement?

Tags: latex, command, indentation

The LaTeX code provided below shows the usage of the command `\indent` as it appears in the document, but it does not produce the desired indentation within the document. Is there a specific package associated with the command `\indent` or `\=`? I´m asking for a step by step method of producing an indentation within a document for only one paragraph, regardless of location within the document.

> \documentclass[12pt]{article}
>
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \topmargin -3.5cm
> \oddsidemargin -0.04cm
> \evensidemargin -0.04cm
> \textwidth 16.59cm
>
> \textheight 21.94cm
>
> \parskip 7.2pt
> \parindent 8pt
> \title{Physics}
>
> \author{Pareshkumar Brahmbhatt}
>
> \date{March 17, 2010}
>
> \begin{document}
> \maketitle
>
> \indent Now we are engaged in a great civil war.
>
> \end{document}

Comment: the code you provided is indented, you just need to have more than one line to see that it is indented...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LaTeX will usually not indent the first paragraph of a section. This is standard typographical practice. However, if you really want to override this default setting, use the package [indentfirst](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/indentfirst.html) available on CTAN.

Answer (score 7):

The first line of a paragraph is indented by default, thus whether or not you have `\indent` there won't make a difference.  `\indent` and `\noindent` can be used to override default behavior.  You can see this by replacing your line with the following:

```
Now we are engaged in a great civil war.\\
\indent this is indented\\
this isn't indented


\noindent override default indentation (not indented)\\
asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack but the best solution that I have found is to use a description tag with no \item. This will produce an error from the latex compiler; however, the error does not prevent the pdf from being generated.

```
\begin{description} 
     <YOUR TEXT HERE> 
\end{description}
```

- This only worked on windows latex compiler